# Let $U, V$ be (open or closed) intervals in $\mathbb R$, and $f: U \rightarrow V$ be increasing and onto. Prove that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $U, V$ be (open or closed) intervals in $\mathbb R$, and let $f: U \rightarrow V$ which is strictly increasing and onto. Prove that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous.

Make a ball around a point in V and map it to a ball in U... ? Really not sure where to go with this. Very lost. I suppose a proof by contradiction may take me somewhere?

Comment: What are $f, f^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $U$ is open. Let $x_0\in U$. Then both limits $F(x-) = \lim_{x\uparrow x_0}F(x)$ and $F(x+)= \lim_{x\downarrow x_0}F(x)$ exist and $F(x-)\le F(x_0)\le F(x+)$. As for every $x<x_0$ we have $F(x)\le F(x-)$ and for all $x>x_0$ we have $F(x)>F(x+)$, the function $F$ could not be onto if $F(x-) < F(x+)$. Hence $F(x-) = F(x_0) = F(x+)$, which shows that $F$ is continuous at $x_0$.

If $U$ is closed you also have to consider the boundary points. But the reasoning is the same.